# Unit Testing.... a data provider?

Tags: unit-testing

Given problem:

- I like unit tests.
- I develop connectivity software to external systems that pretty much and often use a C++ library
- The return of this systems is nonndeterministic. Data is received while running, but making sure it is all correctly interpreted is hard.

How can I test this properly?

I can run a unit test that does a connect. Sadly, it will then process a life data stream. I can say I run the test for 30 or 60 seconds before disconnecting, but getting code ccoverage is impossible - I simply dont even comeclose to get all code paths EVERY ONCE PER DAY (error code paths are rarely run).
I also can not really assert every result. Depending on the time of the day we talk of 20.000 data callbacks per second - all of which are not relly determined good enough to validate each of them for consistency.
Mocking? Well, that would leave me testing an empty shell of myself because the code handling the events basically is the to be tested case, and in many cases we talk here of a COMPLEX c level structure - hard to have mocking frameworks that integrate from Csharp to C++

Anyone any idea? I am short on giving up using unit tests for this part of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing is good, but it shouldn't be your only weapon against bugs. Look into [the difference between unit tests and integration tests](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/): it sounds to me like the latter is your best choice.

Also, automated tests (unit tests and integration tests) are only useful if your system's behavior isn't going to change. If you're breaking backward compatibility with every release, the automated tests of that functionality won't help you.

You may also want to see a previous discussion on [how much unit testing is too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122570/at-what-point-do-you-reach-unit-testing-overkill).

Comment: I take that as answer. I have deleted the test project for this connector and will take a more manual approach by writing a test app that I can run in the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Does your external data source implement an interface -- or can you using a combination of an interface and a wrapper around the data source that implements the interface decouple your class under test from the data source.  If either of these are true, then you can mock out the data source in your unit tests and provide the data from the mock instance.

```
public interface IDataSource
{
     public List<DataObject> All();
     ...
}

public class DataWrapper : IDataSource
{
     public DataWrapper( RealDataSource source )
     {
         this.Source = source;
     }

     public RealDataSource Source { get; set; }

     public List<DataObject> All()
     {
          return this.Source.All();
     }
}
```

Now in your class under test depend on the interface and inject an instance, then in your unit tests, provide a mock instance that implements the interface.

```
public void DataSourceAllTest()
{
    var dataSource = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataSource>();
    dataSource.Expect( s => s.All() ).Return( ... mock data ... );

    var target = new ClassUnderTest( dataSource );

    var actual = target.Foo();

    // assert something about actual

    dataSource.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Comment: There is no "one" of them - there are multiple. Most come as C stle libraries, one as normal dll with header file. As the whole idea is to test that my interaction with them works, I am not sure replaceing them - even if there is a way - is feasible. How do I know I work with them well if my tests just dont work with them?

Comment: I do not think I can mock away the actual functionality I want to test, or?

Comment: @TomTom - there's a difference between unit tests and integration tests.  In unit tests, you do want to mock out the dependencies.  You only want to test your code and make sure it works under the expected (and unexpected) inputs.  You seem to be talking about integration tests.  You need those, too, and no you don't mock out the dependencies for those -- but you also don't have to test your code as extensively, just samples of the interactions.  Your unit tests should ensure that your code works for the normal and corner cases.